# How to query an entity and aggregate the count onto a value object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, count

I am trying to create a query in JPA that will get an id and find the count on multiple columns for the given id.

Eg I have a job, this resource can have attributes added to it. I am required to find the count of every attribute and map onto a new VO for the given job id.

Scenario.

```
Job A has
    1 skillsType assigned

Job B has   
    2 skillsType assigned
```

My database structure saves the `jobId`, `skillType` and `skillTypeId`. As it is, this will give me 2 values for the id of Job B, however i need it to be one row and to give the count of the skillsType by a given type.

I have tried to create a VO on the repository to map the values onto it, however it is not working.

My VO has the following values, `jobId`, `softSkillsCount`, `technicalSkillsCount`

Eg Job B would be 
jobBIdValue, 1, 1 rather than
jobBIdValue, softSkill, skillIdSoft
jobBIdValue, technicalSkill, skillIdTechnical

The code that I have so far is
    `NamedQuery = select new packagename.myJobViewVO(jobId, countOfSoftSkills,countOfTechnicalSkils) from JobView where jobId = 123`

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but following query could do the job

```
select new packagename.myJobViewVO(jobId,
 sum(case when skillType = 'soft' then 1 else 0 end ) as countOfSoftSkills,
 sum(case when skillType = 'hard' then 1 else 0 end ) as countOfTechnicalSkils
) from JobView where jobId = 123 group by jobId
```

Comment: thank you. I will have a go. I ended up creating a new view to do that.